# Google maps loading forever when trying to open a shops location from maps in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mkmapview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a map pin in my details section in my app about specific shops. the details contain the shop's location which users can access and it will redirect them to google maps if they click the pin.

the issue is that if google maps are not already opened in their device (running in the background) it will load forever and won't give navigation routes for the user.

How can I fix this issue?

here is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")! as URL)) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:  "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(self.getFinalLatitude!),\(self.getFinalLongitude!)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)

        } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'getFinalLatitude' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato from my firestore database